# Excel Macro to populate value in column U on sheet1 if column H in sheet1 contains a value listed in column A of sheet 2

Tags: vba, excel

So I'm stumped on this logic for writing a macro and I would love some help!

I have a list of about 1700 different numbers on sheet 2 in column A.  I need a macro to find if those numbers exist in in column H in sheet1, and if they do, to populate column U in the same row with a word or character.

Make sense?

I figured out a way to find if column H in sheet1 has those numbers and to delete the rows, but that's not exactly what I'm going for.  I was just trying to see if I could suss out the logic from the delete row, but not so much.

Thanks in advance!

The code I have so far is:

```
The code I have so far is:
Sub DL()
Dim LR As Long, i As Long
With Sheets("Sheet2")
  LR = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
  For i = LR To 1 Step -1
    If IsNumeric(Application.Match(.Range("A" & i).Value, Sheets("Sheet2").Columns("A"), 0)) Then
```

Comment: What you're looking for doesn't require a macro. Do a search on VLOOKUP. It will allow you to check a range of values, and if a value is found, will return the contents of whatever you tell it to. You can do this across files as easily as across sheets in one file.

Comment: If you actually need to DELETE values, then I stand corrected.  You can't really do that without a macro.  Sorry.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it contains no code.

Comment: You can use a formula and `MATCH()` for this.

Comment: So, it's a little tricky.  I wanted a macro because we have a tab delimited txt datafeed file that is updated daily.  I have a separate spreadsheet containing all of the macros and I just import the txt file to excel and run the macros.  A formula is less than ideal because it would be erased each time the file is overwritten with the new version.

Comment: "populate column U in the same row with a word or character" - Col U on which sheet ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub DL()

Dim LR As Long, i As Long
Dim rngList As Range

    Set rngList = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("H:H") 'lookup list

    With Sheets("Sheet2")
        LR = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
            For i = 1 To LR
            If IsNumeric(Application.Match(.Cells(i, "A").Value, rngList, 0)) Then
                .Cells(i, "U").Value = "Match"
            End If
        Next i
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Tim,
Thanks for this!  In answer to your first question, it needs to populate column U in the first sheet.  Sheet 2 contains the lookup list, and sheet 1 contains the data to confirm and then populate column U.

Anyway, it worked like a charm!  I think the problem was my data in the first place.  I wasn't comparing apples to apples data and I didn't realize it until a vlookup showed me no matches.  

Duh.